# The Sidebar Panel is not showing and my Language configuration is not working (vscode extension)

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

Hey Everyone I need help with my VSCode Extension, There are 2 issues. One is: Sidepanel not showing the content in the Production, and the second is: The new Programming Language I added through the Extension is not giving out snippets or syntax highlighting in Production, but it does show the icon i assigned it.

NOTE: Both of these errors came in Production, they were not there in Development

Link to the Code: https://github.com/Jonak-Adipta-Kalita/JAK-VSCode-Extension

Link to Extension: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=JAKVSCodeExtension.jak-vscode-extension

Comment: Solved the Sidebar Panel problem!! But the Language Configuration problem is still there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved both of the Issues, the code for the SidebarPanel and the Code for the Language Configuration were in the .vscodeignore file